# Is it possible to mount a 7-Segment on an FPC and what points need to be considered?

Tags: pcb-design, fpc, flexible

I am designing a project with a flat flex PCB, in which I would need a 7-Segment display similar to below picture.
I would like to avoid to add an extra PCB with a connector or hot-bar just for the displayand I would also like to avoid a rigid-flex design.

So I thought, why not put it directly to the flat flex...
However what felt like a brilliant idea, after I started searching I found little to no examples, of even through hole components being put on a pure flat flex PCB.

So my questions:

- Is is possible to do?
- If so, why isn't it done often enough to find plenty of examples?
- Are there problem or issues to be expected?
- Is it feasible for mass production?
- Does it, same as for SMD components, require to add stiffener under the flat flex?

[image]

Comment: Yes it'll be possible. It may be prone to fatigue or dry solder joints due to cable flex and vibration. ... if there ARE issues, you may find out a few months after entering mass production. Personally, I wouldn't. Or I'd make a batch but use a sub-PCB for themain production run. If the batch survives well enough, consider it for a cost reduction next year. Stiffener may help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. If the hole thing is mounted steady into a housing (no vibrations), would you still worry about fatigue? Also shouldn't the 2 rows of pins of the display act as a kind of stiffener as well? Do you think this could help? Sorry for so many stupid questions, but till now I haven't worked often with FPC's.

Comment: I often saw SMD-components mounted on FPCs and in my oppinion it should work with THT-components as well. Fatigue wouldn't be a problem if the FPC doesn't move or bend too much, I guess.

Comment: I contacted a manufacturer and they said, it might be ok. 
Anyhow I ordered now some prototype - If no other answers, I'll answer my experience as soon as I tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive discussions with the fabricator and receiving several different variants as protype and then after starting productin, I can answer my own question:

- Yes it is possible to do
- After extensive vibration testing, I can also say fatigue is no issue (at least in my application) if several key points are considered:

  - Do a mechanical modal analysis and make sure no Eigenfrequencies of the FPC are within the expected vibration frequencies
  - Add Stiffener close to the pins (and in best case around) to let the pin be mounted on the smallest possible diameter membrane

    - The best results out of my prototypes I had with 0.2mm FPC + 0.6mm FT4 stiffener
- It is feasible for mass production (no extensive failure rate in production so far)